# Why i can't connect Microsoft SQL Server Compact 3.5 on window CE

Tags: c#, database, windows-ce

I use Visual Studio 2008 Pro

I installed

- Microsoft .net compact framework 2.0 SP2
- Microsoft .net compact framework 3.5

-Microsoft SQL Server Compact 3.5 for Devices ENU

-Microsoft SQL Server Compact 3.5 SP1 Design Tools English

-Microsoft SQL Server Compact 3.5 SP2 ENU

-Microsoft SQL Server Compact 3.5 SP2 x64 ENU

-Microsoft SQL Server Compact 4.0 x64 ENU

**And i do this**

1.create new project -> C# -> smart device project
//[picture step 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ounGd.png)

2.Platform:window CE -> .NET Compact version 3.5 //[picture step 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ezzy5.png)

3.Add new item... //[picture step 3-1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lAnqf.png), and choose Database File//[picture step 3-2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ox9SH.png)

4.It show popup //[picture step 4-1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zNI0e.png), [picture step 4-2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AOtbh.png)

5.I click new connection -> Browse myDB -> Test connection [picture step 5](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w5s4m.png)

6.And i try type myDB and click Create... nothing respone.//[picture step 6][9]

It doesn't show popups like this.//[pic sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BbjNO.png)

**What did I do wrong?**

Comment: Please precise the question, the error could be anything

Comment: try again please

Answer (score 0):

Please run Microsoft Management as Administrator

Comment: Can you expand more info for me